Does temporarily withdrawing from a degree program fall under "required to leave" when applying again for a UK visa to resume studies?
Does temporarily withdrawing from a degree program fall under "required to leave" when applying again for a UK visa to resume studies?

The university is required to notify UKVI of your interruption or withdrawal within 10 working days of the interruption or withdrawal being finalised
Your Student Visa is then cancelled by UKVI (in most cases). Were you advised in writing that you must leave the UK?

Yes, I received a letter in which I was asked to leave within 60 days, which I did. Now I am applying for another Tier 4 student visa again to resume my studies. I am confused because in the visa application process there is a section that states that you were ever deported, refused, required to leave, etc. Does "required to leave" refer to me if I am applying for a new visa to go to the UK?

The university is required to notify UKVI of your interruption or withdrawal within 10 working days of the interruption or withdrawal being finalised. Your Student Visa is then cancelled by UKVI (in most cases).
In a comment you state that you received a letter in which you were asked to leave within 60 days, which you did. So yes, clearly “required to leave” applies to you.
